# C# If Else Statement to choose the appropriate Xpath expression

Tags: c#

I'm writing an automation test using C#, Ranorex dll library and Xpath expressions as my locators. That's all fine but in some scenarios I want to use If Else statement to choose the appropriate Xpath from a possible 2 xpaths:

```
Public class Locators
{
    public const string Xpathone = "//form[@controlname='x1']";
    public const string Xpathtwo = "//form[@controlname='x2']";
}


Step Definition
[Binding]
public class HomePageSteps
{
    public void SelectAppropriateXpath()
    {
        Validate.Exists(HomePage.Header, Config.ExistsTimeOut);
        if (Validate.Exists(HomePage.Xpathone))==true
        {
            mouse.click(HomePage.Xpathone);
        }
        else
        {
            mouse.click(HomePage.Xpathtwo);
        }
    }
```

But I continue to get an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'bool'

Even when I change the type to bool:

> public bool SelectAppropriateXpath()

The error still remains and this is baffling me. And when I do use 'public bool' I also get:

> Error - not all code paths return a value

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: alternatively: remove the `if` completely: `mose.click(Validate.Exists(HomePage.Xpathone) ? HomePage.Xpathone : HomePage.Xpathtwo);`

Comment: Does `Validate.Exists` really return a `bool`?

Comment: @Marc Gravell `mouse.click(Validate.Exists(HomePage.Xpathone) ? HomePage.Xpathone : HomePage.Xpathtwo);` I like this example and didnt know it was possible like this. But I still get an error: **Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'bool'** @Hans Kesting The xpaths relate to elements on a webpage, and they can vary but I want to continue with the test either way. According to the method doc yes it can [http://www.ranorex.com/Documentation/Ranorex/html/Overload_Ranorex_Validate_Exists.htm]

Comment: Validate.Exists({xpath}) has a return value of void, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to keep in mind when using ranorex, even though Validate.Exists({xpath}) will write to a report that the appropriate item has been found the function itself does not return a value.

[Ranorex documentation for this function](http://www.ranorex.com/Documentation/Ranorex/html/M_Ranorex_Validate_Exists_8.htm)

The Correct overload to use is this one:

[Validate with bool return value](http://www.ranorex.com/Documentation/Ranorex/html/M_Ranorex_Validate_Exists_12.htm)

So for this if else your function call should look like this:

```
if(Validate.Exists(HomePage.Xpathone, {Time Duration}, {Log Message}, false))
{
}
```

The == true part of this statement is unnecessary since you are comparing a bool value to a bool.

The answers above will unfortunately not work because the validate function you are using has no return value.

Comment: This is the exact correct answer. Well done theDarse. My methods now look something like this (using the bool Validate.Exists):  

            bool item = Validate.Exists(ActiveCase.CaseOwnerSubtext, Config.WhileLoopPollingTime, "Found", false);

Answer (score 3):

At first glance you have an error in your code:

```
if (Validate.Exists(HomePage.Xpathone))==true
```

Should be:

```
if (Validate.Exists(HomePage.Xpathone))
```

Comment: Thank you for not having `== true` in your suggested correct code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that having steps with conditional logic is a very good idea (assuming you are using SpecFlow or other acceptance testing tool). Tests should be [consistent](http://pragprog.com/magazines/2012-01/unit-tests-are-first). Consider to create two different steps for each condition. E.g. (of course, it's better to use domain-specific language instead of clicking and so on):

```
Given your state
And x1 exists
When click on x1
Then results

Given your state
And x1 not exists
When click on x2
Then other results
```

If you are not dealing with tests, then I suggest you to eliminate duplication of mouse clicking, thus actually you have exactly same logic, only path is changing:

```
var path = Validate.Exists(HomePage.Xpathone) ? HomePage.Xpathone : HomePage.Xpathtwo;
mouse.click(path);
```

Comment: This may be the more helpful answer ultimately.

Comment: @Ashigore thanks, from coding point of view your answer is also totally correct

Comment: As per your suggestion all of my Step Definition methods are done like this and my frame work is designed in the page object pattern. But I think its neater in this scenario where a method can have 20 actions, not to duplicate the method twice, just because 1 action can vary. Hence my plan to use the If Else.

Answer (score -1):

The following peice of code is incorrect:

```
if (Validate.Exists(HomePage.Xpathone))==true
```

It should be:

```
if (Validate.Exists(HomePage.Xpathone) == true)
```